# Replacement light fixture not lighting

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I’m replacing an old light fixture with a new LED one. When I got it all hooked up the light turned on very faintly. I checked the fixture by installing somewhere else and it worked fine. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What kind of switch? One switch or two (3-way)? Dimmer? Motion sensor? Timer?

Comment: Did the old fixture work properly? What kind bulb(s) did it support?

Comment: Have you checked with a volt meter?